# Implement Fan View - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to implement a Fan view like the ones in the Mac OS X dock, such as the Downloads and Documents folders, using Cocoa.

I am currently adding a button on a transparent window's content view and animating the button's frame using `NSViewAnimation` (group animation). But the animation is not as smooth as expected.

Is there any other optimized way for implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for this. You should create a transparent view/window that's large enough to contain your whole animation. You should then use `CALayer` objects to perform the actual animation.

Core Animation layers are essentially high-level lightweight wrappers around OpenGL surfaces and the rendering of the layers is done by the GPU, giving much better performance than CPU-managed animation such as `NSViewAnimation`.

Bear in mind that because Core Animation layers are lightweight, they don't have any event-handling built into them, so you'll need to do all the mouse tracking in your view/view controller.

Your other option is using layer-backed views (which have their own `CALayer`) and animating the buttons' positions using the animator proxy. This may be enough to achieve what you want, and because the buttons are still full `NSButton` objects they still have all the `NSView` event handling.

You should probably read the [Animation Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/Animation_Overview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004952-CH9-SW1) to give you a better idea of how all these technologies work.